# How i add text on my slide image

Tags: html, css

I use some text on my slider images, I use some trick but I am something going wrong here is my css and html:

**CSS**

```
.banner {float:left; width:100%; position:relative;}
.container {margin:0 auto; width:200px;}
.inban {float:left; width:100%; position:absolute; z-index:99; top:0px; left:0px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
<img src="banner-1.jpg" alt="">
<div class="inban">
    <div class="container">
        Test text
    </div>
</div>
```

Please give me some idea how I add text over the image and in my container.

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle link to provide your code. Don't forget an image.

Comment: here is my fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/anmol1976/msmxrd99/embedded/result/

Comment: sorry this is updated link:

https://jsfiddle.net/anmol1976/msmxrd99/1/

Comment: Yes. The jsfiddle demo works fine for me too.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the image in as a background image of the wrapping div would be easier, but in this scenario I see the images as content, and thus belongs in the HTML. We'll use that wrapping div as a container for absolute positioning.

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/CCC" alt="">
<div class="inban">
    <div class="container image">
         <h2><span>A Movie in the Park:<span class='spacer'></span><br /><span class='spacer'></span>Kung Fu Panda</span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h2 span { 
color: white; 
font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
letter-spacing: -1px;  
background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
padding: 10px; 
}

.image { 
position: relative; 
width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}
```

**Fixing Semantics**

When an inline element breaks, the block breaks **immediately** after the last character in the line, and begins **immediately** flush left on the next line. Padding, in this case, does not help us.

To solve this, we'll apply some more spans on either side of the 
 element to simulate that padding.

```
$(function() {

$("h2")
    .wrapInner("<span>")

$("h2 br")
    .before("<span class='spacer'>")
    .after("<span class='spacer'>");

});
```

You can find working JSFiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ravanliyski/vc5hr1mm/)

Comment: Instead of a `span`, which you are taking more code, introduce a `div`, and then, if you want/need it, add a span to it, so you don't need to add unnecesary jquery code.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo: Animated Text Overlay On Hover</title>
<style>
.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
}

.box img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

.box .overbox {
  background-color: #304562;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 360px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 130px 20px;
}

.box:hover .overbox { opacity: 1; }

.box .overtext {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
}

.box .title {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.box:hover .title,
.box:focus .title {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
}

.box .tagline {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.box:hover .tagline,
.box:focus .tagline {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="margin:150px auto 50px auto">Demo: Animated Text Overlay On Hover</h1>
<div class="box"> <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
  <div class="overbox">
    <div class="title overtext"> Text Demo </div>
    <div class="tagline overtext"> Hover Text is Load </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-46156385-1', 'cssscript.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

**CSS**

```
.banner{float:left; width:100%;position:relative; text-align:center;}
.container{margin:0 auto; width:960px;}
.inban{ width:100%; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;}
img{max-width:100%; height:auto;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="banner">
<img src="banner-1.jpg" alt="">
<div class="inban">
        Test text
    </div>
</div>
```